# Pagination links not working for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, paginate-links

I have a Custom Post Type (project) and a Custom Taxonomy (project_category).

I have created a Page (Projects), which uses a custom template, in which I run a WP_Query to fetch projects and display with a pagination, using the paginate_links function.

To display the custom taxonomy archive I use a template named taxonomy-project_category.blade.php (Blade because I'm using Roots Sage).

The projects and the pagination display correctly. The pagination works well when parsing the projects list. But it displays a 404 page when clicking on the pagination links of a project_category page.

- /projects/ works, it displays the list of projects, page 1
- /projects/page/2 works, it displays the list of projects, page 2
- /project_category/category1 works, it displays the list of projects having the category1, page 1
- /project_category/category1/page/2 does NOT work, it displays a 404 page.

Here is my call to paginate_links :

```
paginate_links( [
    'total'    => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'  => get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ),
    'show_all' => true,
] )
```

Any idea why the URL /project_category/category1/page/2 is 404 instead of the taxonomy archive paginated page ?

Comment: it's probably because although your custom `WP_Query` has a second page, the main query that loaded the template that lives at that URL does not. Creating a custom query with `WP_Query` is not how you change the results, it's a second new additional set of queries. If you want to change which posts the main query displays or change parameters then you should change it using the `pre_get_posts` filter, and then all of this pagination workaround code and the bugs dissappear.

Comment: Note I am assuming that `/projects` uses a page template, and `/project_category` uses `taxonomy-project_category.php` or equivalent theme template. If this is not the case please edit this info into your question so that it's clearer

Comment: You're right @TomJNowell, I'm using a page template and tax template. I've edited my question.

Comment: Ok... the /project_category/category1/page/2 URL is returning a 404 because there are no projects to display on page 2.... I just have 2 projects for this term in DB and I display 10 posts per page... ‍